# Checking linguistic validity

Tags: syntax, nlp, semantic-analysis

Are there any [open source] code libraries for checking a sentence's linguistic validity according to syntax and semantics?

Comment: What aspects of semantics do you want to check?

Comment: @dmcer I'm not sure of the OP's intent, but analyzing anaphora may be a useful test on the boundary of syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 0):

No.

That being said, there's libraries that can check a sentence's syntactic probability. (Semantics not so much, computers have very little to no sense of 'meaning').

Check out nltk for Python, or Google "NLP" toolkit and see what you can find.

Answer (score 0):

For the syntax, you would have to hardcode it into a fast parsing algorithm like CLE, rejecting certain structures based on linguistic validity.

Answer (score 0):

See [write-good](https://github.com/btford/write-good)

Install:

```sh
sudo npm install write-good
```

Usage:

```sh
$ write-good --text="My wallet was stolen."
In text
=============
My wallet was stolen.
          ^^^^^^^^^^
"was stolen" may be passive voice on line 1 at column 10
```

Or

```
$ write-good file.txt
```